# Percentile on column in data frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy, percentile

Have following code w/ output. Looking to add percentiles for each %total for the 'event' category - 'GOAL' 'MISS' 'SHOT' in relation to all entries across the entire dataset for each event category.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do a `groupby` on the `'event'` column and then use the `.rank` method with the argument `pct=True`. Using a sample df:

```
event_perc = pd.DataFrame({'shooterName':['A']*3+['B']*3+['C']*3, 'event':["GOAL","MISS","SHOT"]*3, 'count':[1,15,20,5,10,35,9,30,70]})
event_perc.set_index(["shooterName","event"], inplace=True)
event_perc['%total'] = event_perc.groupby('shooterName')['count'].apply(lambda x: x/sum(x))
```

---

```
>>> event_perc
                   count    %total
shooterName event                 
A           GOAL       1  0.027778
            MISS      15  0.416667
            SHOT      20  0.555556
B           GOAL       5  0.100000
            MISS      10  0.200000
            SHOT      35  0.700000
C           GOAL       9  0.082569
            MISS      30  0.275229
            SHOT      70  0.642202
```

Then we can create a new column called `"event_percentile"` which gives you each shooter's percentile for that particular event among all of the shooters.

```
event_perc['event_percentile'] = event_perc.groupby("event")['%total'].rank(pct=True)
```

And we get the following result:

```
>>> event_perc
                   count    %total  event_percentile
shooterName event                                   
A           GOAL       1  0.027778          0.333333
            MISS      15  0.416667          1.000000
            SHOT      20  0.555556          0.333333
B           GOAL       5  0.100000          1.000000
            MISS      10  0.200000          0.333333
            SHOT      35  0.700000          1.000000
C           GOAL       9  0.082569          0.666667
            MISS      30  0.275229          0.666667
            SHOT      70  0.642202          0.666667
```

Comment: Wow, that's huge + very informative - thank you!